# Outlook rule is not working where recipient is part of a distribution list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I have a rule that if I am cc'ed on email then move it to a folder called "CC".

If someone sends an email to a distribution list where the distribution list is cc'ed, shouldn't that email also go into the "CC" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For distribution lists you are BCC'd instead of CC'd. Just add another rule for that.